# Are there male mangaka who do shoujo manga?

Tags: manga-production, mangaka

Even if a shoujo manga is made commonly by female mangaka are there male mangakas who do shoujo mangas?

Comment: Wedding Peach mangaka is male although the artist is female

Comment: if you don't want to wait for the answer, you can find out yourself by going through a list of shoujo manga titles and checking out each author's profile to see if they're male https://myanimelist.net/manga/genre/25/Shoujo

Comment: Just browse a bit, even Osamu Tezuka made quite a lot shoujo manga ([13 based on manga update](https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=1356)), although most of his work are shounen

Comment: the first part of [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3975/2869) can answer your question. In short, yes there are male manga who make shoujo manga

Answer (score 3):

The answer is trivially yes. I offer as evidence [*Himitsu no Akko-chan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himitsu_no_Akko-chan) (quite a seminal work in its genre), which is written by [AKATSUKA Fujio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujio_Akatsuka), who is by all appearances a man.

People of all genders write all kinds of things. This should hardly come as a surprise.